# Why is my Html.DropDownListFor not displaying the model's value correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to create drop down lists to set the values of elements in an array. I have this plain object to hold the details of a single room

```
public class RoomOccupants
{
    public int adults { get; set; }
    public int children { get; set; }
    public int infants { get; set; }
}
```

And an array of these objects on my model to hold the information of all the rooms

```
public RoomOccupants[] rooms { get; set; }
```

In my razor template I'm creating the drop down lists like this

```
<label>Guests in Room 1</label><br />
<label>Adults</label>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.rooms[0].adults, Model.passengerOptions, new { autocomplete = "off" })

<label>Children</label>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.rooms[0].children, Model.passengerOptions, new { autocomplete = "off" })

<label>Infants</label>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.rooms[0].infants, Model.passengerOptions, new { autocomplete = "off" })
```

The Model.passengerOptions is a list of SelectListItem for the integers 0 - 9, Which I'm using in several different drop downs. It's created in the constructor of the model like this.

```
passengerOptions = new List<SelectListItem>();
passengerOptions.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "0", Text = "0"});
passengerOptions.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "1" });
passengerOptions.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "2" });
passengerOptions.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "3" });
passengerOptions.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "4" });
passengerOptions.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "5", Text = "5" });
passengerOptions.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "6", Text = "6" });
passengerOptions.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "7", Text = "7" });
passengerOptions.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "8", Text = "8" });
passengerOptions.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "9", Text = "9" });
```

When I debug the code I can see that my model contains the correct values, but all the drop down lists always display 0.

I've created some drop downs that work fine on the same page using the same list of options, but they are not in arrays, so maybe that's it?

Comment: what is `Model.passengerOptions` ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code posted unless `Model.passengerOptions` contains something odd.

Comment: comment last two dropdownlist code and see what happens

Comment: This is an unfortunate limitation of using `DropDownListFor()` in a loop (has been reported as a bug on CodePlex numerous times). You need to generate a new `SelectList` each time.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Thanks. That seems to have been what my problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly that whether this is because of array,it may have.
Instead of that try, List ..This will work Correctly.

public  List < SelectedListItem > rooms {get;set;} in model.

And you can directly use the property of model.

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.infants , Model.passengerOptions, new { autocomplete = "off" })

Thanks.

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.children , Model.passengerOptions, new { autocomplete = "off" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.adults, Model.passengerOptions, new { autocomplete = "off" })

Thank You. :)